# Начать цикл заново

Tags: c, циклы

Нужно, чтобы цикл снова отработал при 0 n 3. У меня программа зацикливается.

```
for( a = 0; a < 1; a++ )
{
    scanf( "%i", &n );
    if( n == 1 ) i=1;
    if( n == 2 ) i=2;
    if( n == 3 ) i=3;

    if( n < 1 || n > 3 ) {
        puts( "давай сначала" );
        a = -1;
        i=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `что-то( n ) = 0` вот это как нужно понимать?

Comment: а зачем цикл заводить для перебора от `0` до `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как один и тот же цикл можно записать разными способами, то существует много подходов к решению вашей задачи. Например, цикл может выглядеть следующим образом. Имейте в виду, что пользователь может прервать ввод, и вам следует обработать такую ситуацию.

```
n = 0;

while ( scanf( "%i", &n ) == 1 && ( n < 1 || n > 3 ) )
{ 
    puts( "давай сначала" );
    n = 0;
}

i = n;
```

или последнее предложение в зависимости от контекста можно заменить на

```
if ( n != 0 ) i = n;
```

Или если в реальном коде у вас не совсем такое прямолинейное присвоение, как

```
if( n == 1 ) i=1;
```

а есть некоторая зависимость значения переменной `i` от перечисления значений переменной `n`, то вы можете записать

```
int valid = 0;

while ( !valid && scanf( "%i", &n ) == 1 )
{
    valid = 1;

    switch( n )
    {
    case 1:  
        i = 1; break;
    case 2:
        i = 2; break;
    case 3:
        i = 3; break;
    default:
        puts( "давай сначала" );
        valid = 0;
    }        
}
```

Или

```
int valid = 0;

while ( !valid && scanf( "%i", &n ) == 1 )
{
    valid = 1;

    switch( n )
    {
    case 1: case 2: case 3:  
        i = n; 
        break;
    default:
        puts( "давай сначала" );
        valid = 0;
        break;
    }        
}
```

Вы можете ввести перечисления, чтобы для магических чисел 1, 2, 3 ввести мнемонические имена. Например, если эти значения соответствуют пунктам некоторого меню, то вы можете написать, допустим

```
enum { Exit = 0, Add = 1, Division = 2, Multiply = 3 };

i = Exit;

while ( i == Exit && scanf( "%i", &n ) == 1 )
{
    switch( n )
    {
    case Add: case Division: case Multiply:  
        i = n; 
        break;
    default:
        puts( "давай сначала" );
        break;
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
while (true)
{
  scanf("%d", &n);

  ...

  if (n >= 1 && n <= 3)
    break;

  puts("давай сначала");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(;;puts( "давай сначала" ))
{
    int n = scanf( "%i", &i );
    scanf("%*[^\n]s");
    if( n != 1 || (i >= 1 && i <= 3)) break;
}
```

Comment: это специально так: вводить `i`, а потом переписывать ее неинициализированной переменной `n`?

Comment: @Grundy Заказчик - барин :) Все, как у него - ему виднее :)

Comment: А вот и нет :Р у него **вводится** `n`, и потом это значение присваивается `i`. так что у него все правильно!

Comment: @Grundy Ну хорошо, хорошо... Что б оставить? О! оставлю оба - смотрите...

Comment: а зачем второй scanf? :)

Comment: @Grundy Потому что если ввести что-то типа "abc" (ну, в смысле, строку) вместо числа, это "abc" будет сидеть в буфере и мешать программе работать...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49433/discussion-between-grundy-and-harry).

Answer (score -1):

```
do
{
  scanf( "%i", &i );
  if (i < 1 || i > 3)
    puts("давай сначала");
} while (i < 1 || i > 3)
```